# How to create a method in a class that would "connect to my Database" on calling?

Tags: c#, database, oop, class, oledb

Can someone please tell me how can I create a method in a class that would execute the following code on calling ???

```
OledbConnection con;
private void createcon()
{
    con = new OleDbConnection();

    string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string DBPath = "";
    if (Directory.Exists(currentPath + @"\Database") == true)
    {
        DBPath = currentPath + @"\Database\SMAStaff.accdb";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            currentPath = currentPath.Remove(currentPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        }
        DBPath = currentPath + "\\Database\\SMAStaff.accdb";
    }
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath + ";" +
    "Persist Security Info = False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123";
}
```

This method is present on every form of my project so I think creating a class would be a better idea. I'm able to accomplish this but 
when I call

```
con.open()
```

nothing happens and an error is shown in the error window. The name con doesnot exist in the current context. I know what that means but I don't know how to get past it. I've tried to make "con" public and internal but still noting happens ...
If someone could help with this I would be grateful ...
Thank you

Comment: Instead of messing around with string manipulation on file paths, consider looking into the [`System.IO.Path`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx) class; it has lots of useful methods to do it for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can change the return type of method, and if you put this on new classes you must change private to public:

```
public OledbConnection createcon()
{
   OledbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();

    string currentPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
    string DBPath = "";
    if (Directory.Exists(currentPath + @"\Database") == true)
    {
        DBPath = currentPath + @"\Database\SMAStaff.accdb";
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            currentPath = currentPath.Remove(currentPath.LastIndexOf("\\"));
        }
        DBPath = currentPath + "\\Database\\SMAStaff.accdb";
    }
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + DBPath + ";" +
    "Persist Security Info = False;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=123";


    return con;

}
```

So you can use like this: `classInstance.createcon().open();`

Comment: Yeah it works, Thanks.
Can you please explain why con needs to be returned. I mean why can't I write classInstance.createcon().con.open(); ??? 
I know it doesn't work but can you clear my concept ???

Also we can use Internal identifier rather than public right ???

Your help will be appreciated ... @Saeid

Comment: @WaqasAli Read for AccessModifiers here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @WaqasAli And Why your method not worked its all about the variable scope in C# if all of these issues like call the `con.open()` and define of `createcon()` method be in the same class (in same scope) then your method must be worked!